# Schrodingers dictionary: getting values for dynamic keys on indirect access

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I want to create a specialised dictionary that has some dynamic keys. Subclassing `dict` and overriding `__getitems__` gets me most of the way there however you only get the value of key from the last direct access.

```
$ cat schrodingers_dict.py
cats = []

class SchrodingersDict(dict):
    def __getitem__(self, key):
        if key == 'dead' or key == 'alive':
            self[key] = cats.count(key)
        return super().__getitem__(key)

box = SchrodingersDict([('dead', 0), ('alive', 0)])

$ python3 -i schrodinger_dict.py 
>>> box
{'dead': 0, 'alive': 0}
>>> cats.append('alive')
>>> cats.append('dead')
>>> cats.append('dead')
>>> box
{'dead': 0, 'alive': 0}
>>> box['dead']
2
>>> box['alive']
1
>>> box
{'dead': 2, 'alive': 1}
```

Is it possible to have indirect access return dynamic values such as `repr(box)` or `json.dumps(box)`?

Comment: I am not sure if I understand correctly. In this example, as soon as the content of cat changes, the output of `repr(box)` or `json.dumps(box)` is supposed to change? Or is the actual `value` stored for the keys supposed to change?

Comment: @bbastu I want the value to change on indirect access such as `repr`, `dumps`. I don't need `cat` to signal the `dict` when it changes, I just want the value to be correct when the dict is display or serialized ect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should probably extend `MutableMapping` and implement the relevant abstract methods (delegating to a concrete underlying dict for non-computed keys), because due to performance optimisations `dict` is not guaranteed to call `__getitem__` when e.g. iterating on k/v.

```
$ cat schrodingers_dict.py
from collections import MutableMapping
cats = []

class SchrodingersDict(MutableMapping):

    def __init__(self, data):
        self._store = dict(data)

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        if key == 'dead' or key == 'alive':
            self._store[key] = cats.count(key)
        return self._store[key]

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        self._store[key] = value

    def __delitem__(self, key):
        del self._store[key]

    def __iter__(self):
        return iter(self._store)

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self._store)

    def __repr__(self):
        return repr(dict(self.items()))


box = SchrodingersDict([('dead', 0), ('alive', 0)])
cats.append('dead')
cats.append('dead')
cats.append('alive')

$ python3 -i schrodinger_dict.py
>>> box
{'dead': 2, 'alive': 1}
```

You may also want to have the computed keys be fully virtual instead of storing them in the underlying dict, you're recomputing them on every access anyway, might as well save some instructions and space.

Comment: @iiSeymour it does not, json.dumps uses iter/iteritems which will not take virtual keys in account. Since you *have* to implement `__iter__` on a Mapping and every relevant method is routed through that (and/or `__getitem__`) you can properly add your virtual keys there and fallback on an inner dict for the rest, and things will work just fine for *every* higher-level method, which is not the case for `dict`.

Comment: @iiSeymour https://repl.it/Iv2Y `dict` basically provides no guarantee if you override its methods (they could be bypassed), Mapping requires implementing a specific set of methods and guarantees that higher-level calls *will* go through these.

Answer (score 0):

The goal is to somehow automatically compute the values for `'dead'` and `'alive'` when the values of the `dict` are being accessed.

However, it is not simply possible to implement a check for access to some kind of `values` attribute within `__getattribute__`, because `dict` is a (C-based) python built-in and does not have an attribute like that. Additionally, special method lookup bypasses `__getattribute__` because of speed optimisations.

Unfortunately, there is no exposed common method for the methods of `dict` to access values (`values`, `items` only return views, everything is handled internally), so that it is necessary for all these methods to explicitly update beforehand.

One solution would be to override every such function in the style of

```
def accessing_method(self):
    self._update_dead_and_alive()
    return super().accessing_method()
```

The other would be programmatically

```
from functools import wraps

cats = []    

def add_state_update(cls):
    # all the methods accessing values of dict
    accmethods_names = [
        '__repr__', '__getitem__', 'get', 'items', 'pop', 'popitem',
        'setdefault', 'values'
    ]

    def state_update(method):
        def update_dead_and_alive(self):
            self['dead'] = cats.count('dead')
            self['alive'] = cats.count('alive')

        @wraps(method)
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            update_dead_and_alive(*args)
            return method(*args, **kwargs)
        return wrapper

    # put update_dead_and_alive in front of the execution of every
    # accmethod
    for n in accmethods_names:
        method = getattr(cls, n)
        setattr(cls, n, state_update(method))

    return cls

@add_state_update
class SchrodingersDict(dict):
    pass

box = SchrodingersDict([('dead', 0), ('alive', 0)])
```

Which gives the following results when tested against the mentioned functions

```
>>> cats.append('alive')
>>> cats.append('dead')
>>> cats.append('dead')
>>>
>>> import pickle
>>> pickle.loads(pickle.dumps(box))
{'dead': 2, 'alive': 1}
>>>
>>> cats.append('alive')
>>> import json
>>> json.loads(json.dumps(box))
{'dead': 2, 'alive': 2}
>>>
>>> cats.append('alive')
>>> eval(repr(box)) == box
True
```

The first version leads to a similiar amount of code and is more explicit, probably.